# keras:: How to find the class-wise accuracy?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, precision-recall

I have a `data-set` contains two types of objects. Lets say `"cat"` and `"dog"`. I want to find the `class-wise` accuracy in Keras. This is what I did;

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
Y_test = np.argmax(y_val, axis=1) # Convert one-hot to index
y_pred = model.predict_classes(x_val)
print(classification_report(Y_test, y_pred))
```

I got the output like this;

[image]

From this output (`0`, `1`) how do I know which belongs to class `cat`, and which belongs to class `dog`?

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy can be calculated at overall model level not at class level, where as precision, Recall are can be calculated at class level.

To calculate accuracy you can use below function

```
keras.metrics.accuracy(y_true, y_pred)
```

You can add `target_names` argument to your `classification_report` as below to understand labels.

```
target_names = ["Class {}".format(i) for i in range(num_classes)]
print(classification_report(Y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

There is one more approach to print the labels and understand what the first and second indices represent. Here is the example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

# define example
data = ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']

values = np.array(data)

#Binary encode
lb = LabelBinarizer()

labels = lb.fit_transform(values)
labels = to_categorical(labels)
print("which position represents for cat and dog?:")
print("Data is:",data)
print(labels)
```

Output:

```
which position represents for cat and dog?:
Data is: ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

From the output you can easily understand, the first indice is for the cat and second is for dog.